# Creating 3D block from the perimeter of an object

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make a script which creates a block with flat surface and bottom, with the sides following the stencil (seen from above) from a 3D object.

Basically I want to go from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

The closest I've gotten is to flatten a object by setting the Z-axis to 0, in hopes of being able to extrude that upwards again. However that doesn't truly flatten it, as you still have all the inner vertices and 2 layers of faces on top of each other

[image]

I can remove the "innards" manually in the editor, however the project I'm working on requires that it's done more or less automatically through code, so I need something that is repeatable and without manually going in and deleting vertices.

Comment: Is the bottom of the original object flat?

Comment: @MartyFouts Not necessarily, no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy with Geometry Nodes. The idea is to isolate the bottom faces, then extrude them.

[image: Geometry Nodes: Separate and Extrude Bottom]

Extra steps will be required in case the bottom isn't flat and without holes. I can't say for sure from the pictures you posted.

To isolate the bottom you'll need to find the face with the lowest Z through the **Attributes Statistics** node. You'll zero the other axes to be able to compare all faces Z against your target, the Min Z.

The **Face is Planar** check is optional. You can combine it to the Z check to ignore faces that fall within the **Equal** node's Epsilon but aren't planar for some reason.

After separating the desired faces, you can then **Extrude** them to get the top and sides of your solid mesh. The normals will be wrong when using a negative offset like I did, so you'll need to flip the faces before welding the bottom to it:

[image: Flip and Weld]

I plugged a few options into the Group Input for ease of use. Tweak values as needed.

Comment: What type of node is that "Face is planar" node?

Comment: @Excludos It's a new node from the beta or alpha versions. Since it's an extra check performed to catch bad faces in the unlikely event someone stuck something not planar to the bottom, you can safely skip that part of the tree. Let me know if the bottom of your meshes has holes/isn't planar so I can add a method to deal with those to the answer. In this case please add pictures of it.

Comment: ah yes, sorry. The bottom isn't necessarily flat, and can (and in this case does) have holes in it

Comment: @Excludos Is the outer boundary of the meshes—the outer edge of the "walls"—continuous? (Please include the requested pictures in your question)